# Hadoop - Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Text> to List<String>

Tags: java, arrays, list, hadoop, hashset

I want to convert `Text distinctWords[]` to `List<String>` with this code:

```
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(distinctWords);
```

But it gives an error

```
Hadoop - Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Text> to List<String>.
```

How do I convert `List<Text>` to `List<String>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Text` is not a `String`, direct conversion cannot be done. However, this can be done with a simple for-each:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<> ();
for (Text text : distinctWords) {
    strings.add(text.toString());
}
```

Or with Java 8 streams

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.stream(distinctWords)
    .map(word -> word.toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir for answering. I'm trying that solution.